# How to get data from UIWebView pass to Native app in Objective-c IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, sms

I have a problem. I wanted to get data from webview pass to native application in IOS. I had searched on the internet but I tried manay solution they didn't work for me. My objective is I wanted click on a button in Webview it will remote open the SMS in Native app and set data to body of SMS from Webview. Please help me. Thanks for in advance.

Comment: show your code.... clearly

Comment: Do you want to get sms body from webView? as a text?

Comment: Yes, sure. I wanted that.

Comment: Thank for reply comment. Maybe use knew about the <a href="sms:12345678?body=Hello my friend">Send SMS</a> we can not use this in IOS 7 or later. So I wanted to click on a link or button to open the new compose of SMS and set data from webview to body of SMS.

Comment: @yucel bayram  Yes I want to set the SMS body from webview and also as a text.

Comment: You need to take this text from web view? Do you have an idea about it? You want to highlight text and take highlighted text to sms or simply click and choose whole text?  explain it and i ll try to show you way.

Comment: @yucel bayram thanks for your reply. My way is in my WebView I have a <button>Go SMS</button> and <input type="hidden" id="bodysms" value="This is my content of SMS will be set!" />, So when I clicked on button it will be open new compose SMS and set the text that get from value of <input type="hidden">, Example: document.getElementById("bodysms").value();

Comment: If you are writing a native app without phonegap. You cannot control objective c stuffs from javascript. Only you can rule to javascript from objective-c and get return from javascript functions.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `UIWebviewDelegate` method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Create a custom URL scheme (do not register it in the plist)  that is only intended for communication: `bogus-scheme://somedatahere`, identify that in the delegate method and return `NO` but then have your app do whatever it wants, like using the data to open an `MFMessageComposeViewController` from your app, without having to leave your app.

Comment: I already implement the that method with return No; with call a function in html  NSString *returnvalue =  [self.myWebview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myFunction();"]; but that method not call.

Comment: My html and content js like this(local html file) funcion myFunction(){
        alert("Function has been called!");
 }

Comment: But it doesn't appear anything.

Comment: Note: This is potentially susceptible to a kind of hack in where another app registers your "bogus-scheme" as their app's URL scheme, causing your webView to open their app along w/ passing your information to their app. Maybe it could be called `URL-Scheme reverse injection` — Therefor I recommend using a nil scheme, that is, just `://` with noting infront of it.